# running XAMPP does not work

Tags: mysql, xampp

i've tried to download XAMPP, untar it in /opt/lampp and launch

```
sudo ./lamp start
```

but i get this output:

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.7.7...
XAMPP: Another web server daemon is already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...
XAMPP: Couldn't start MySQL!
XAMPP: XAMPP-ProFTPD is already running.
XAMPP for Linux started.
```

so i opened synaptic and i have installed mysql server.

now i have 2 problems, if i restart my ubuntu 10.10:

1. every time i restart my ubuntu i have to retype

   sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
2. if after stop mysql daemon i relaunch lampp i get same message: XAMPP: Couldn't start MySQL!

/var/log/mysql.err and /var/log/mysql.log are empty..

Comment: This is why I avoid wrappers like xampp, and install Apache, MySQL, and whatever else I need individually.  Each of them is easy to install and maintain, but adding another layer around them just makes it more complicated, IMHO.  It seems like you already have most of it, so why not use what you have instead of fighting it?

Comment: and adding to @MartyFried do not use XAMPP for a production setup. XAMPP has been designed for developers to get on with developing at localhost and not to have the worry about the security mechanics of the server suite and so security has been set in the configuration files as a low priority because the servers have no need to be open to the Internet - your PC firewall correctly configured will block most intruders.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've resolved in this way:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp
sudo chown -hR nobody /opt/lampp
sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/lampp
```

then I noticed that I have another mysqld instance running and stoped it with:

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

Comment: Thank you for "sudo service mysql stop". Xampp's mysql couldn't start because there was another mysql daemon running. However, running /etc/init.d/mysql stop seemed to stop and immediately start it up again. Your command worked permanently.

Answer (score 6):

[This post on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835348/mysql-database-cannot-start-on-xampp-for-mac) helped me:

1. Open `etc` folder in the XAMPP installation directory.
2. Find `my.cnf` file and open it in any text editor
3. Change Port from 3306 to 3307 (if you have installed skype or other apps)
4. Add `innodb_force_recovery=1` under `myisam_sort_buffer_size=8M`
5. Save `my.cnf` file
6. Open xampp: 
   Goto Computer(opt)> Open lampp folder(Search "lampp" if u can't see lampp folder)> Open manager-linux.run
7. In XAMPP Click on "Manage Server" Tab> Click on "Mysql Database"> Click on "Configure"> Change Port from 3306 to 3307> save and start the mysql database.

You get a message "Starting MySQL SUCCESS!"

Comment: innodb_force_recovery=1, worked for me

Comment: change port worked for me

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

It worked for me.

Comment: If your Apache Web Server stopped working after these commands then run the following command `sudo apachectl stop` then start your apache web Server...It will work...